# Make a difference backup between two .bak or database and .bak

Tags: sql-server, compare, backup, difference

I am working on SQL Server 2017. I have took the backup and restore the database.
is there any way that I can make a difference backup whether the data between these two continue .bak (example: one is making on june-1 , another is making on july-1)?
or any script(tool) that I can run or check [could be table by table] and export difference backup?

Comment: Offtopic - belongs on dba. Short answer is no - without planning from you/your dba. And there is a hint of an idea here that you want to that "difference" to be generated as a script that can be applied to a different database or perhaps readable by a person/application. And that is a definite NO.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i think i don't clarify the question

Comment: Monthly , i will get a .bak file include about 100 tables and it is extracted (full backup) from another big database (more than 100 tables), the .bak file doesn't have any history like insert、delete etc .and now , a mission is making a difference backup between monthly .bak file and deliver to another user, but i dont have any idea for this now , these is my totally question , and please kindly help me , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you back up a database there are a few options. I think you are asking how to do a differential backup?
The information relating to differential backups can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/differential-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
The first thing to note is that you need a full backup as the 'base' upon which you are to do a differential backup.
The code used to do a differential backup of the AdventureWorks Database to the standard SQL Server Backup location is the following:

```
Use Master;
Go

Backup Database AdventureWorks2017 to DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\AdventureWorks2017_New.Bak'
With Differential
```

This will take a short amount of time as it will only back up the difference in the database since the last full back up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i think i don't clarify the question.

Comment: Monthly , i will get a .bak file  include about 100 tables and it is extracted (full backup) from another big database (more than 100 tables), the .bak file doesn't have any history like insert、delete etc  .and now , a mission is making a difference backup between monthly .bak file and deliver to another user, but i dont have any idea for this now , these is my totally question , and please kindly help me , thanks.